# Odd NullPointerException when using File[] in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have the following function, which I use to update the appearance of some JLists that I have in a GUI:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void updateView(JList list, String path, String file_ext) {
    DefaultListModel list_model = new DefaultListModel();

    System.out.println(path);

    File dir = new File(path);

    if(dir.exists()) System.out.println("File Exists");

    File[] list_of_files = dir.listFiles();

    for (int itr = 0 ; itr < list_of_files.length ; itr++) {
        if (list_of_files[itr].isFile()) {
            if (endsWith(list_of_files[itr].getName(), file_ext)) {
                if(list.equals(codemon_list)) {
                    list_model.addElement(list_of_files[itr].getName());
                } else {
                    list_model.addElement(removeFileExt(list_of_files[itr].getName()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    list.setModel(list_model);
}
```

I create a File object based on the passed 'path', this path is to a directory.  The File is then used to create a File[] (a list of all files in the directory). I then loop through the files and add ones that end in a certain extension to the JList.

However, I am getting a NPE at the initialization line of the for loop.  Even if the directory exists and contains files, I still get a NPE.  I have no idea what going on...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `File#listFiles` will return `null` when the `File` reference doesn't exists, isn't a directory or is a special "type" of file, like a symbolic line, like "My Documents" or "My Music" on Windows

Comment: Its not accessing any special directories, like My Music or that. And after I create the file, I check to make sure it exists, and it does, and I still get a NPE anyways

Comment: Does the process have read permission on the directory?

Comment: Other files in the same GUI use the exact same file path and have no problems.

Comment: Try using `File#isDirectory` as well to check to see if the path is actually a directory